# Why does my simple-html-dom allows e.g. 'ä' for wikipedia but not for wikisource?

Tags: php, parsing, character-encoding, wikipedia, simple-html-dom

My problem is that the following script works with some IRI's and with others not, and my question is why does it behave this way and how to solve it.
I think there is problem with the charset but it's only a guess because in Wikipedia it works.

```
<?php
include('C:\xampp\htdocs\php\simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Am_B%C3%A4chle');
//Titel
foreach($html->find('span#ws-title') as $f)
echo $f->plaintext;

//1   http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/7._August_1929           OK
//2   http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/%E2%80%99s_ist_Krieg!    -
//3   http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Am_B%C3%A4chle           -
//4   http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume-Aff%C3%A4re     OK
//5   http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Solidit%C3%A4t           -
?>
```

The 5 IRI's are the examples. The last 3 IRI's contain %C3%A4,  it's an "ä" but only the one from wikipedia works. The 2. IRI contains %E2%80%99 it's an " ’ " - doesn't work.

But the first IRI from wikisource works. The same for every IRI from wikisource which does not contain any ä, ö, ...

When it does not work I get the following warning:

> **Warning:** file_get_contents(http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Solidit%C3%A4t): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 70
>
> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\frage.php on line 5

The function which contains line 70 in simple_html_dom.php looks like that:

```
//65    function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
//66    {
//67    // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
//68    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $defaultBRText);
//69    // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
//70    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
//71    // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
//72    //    $contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
//73    if (empty($contents))
//74    {
//75        return false;
//76    }
//77    // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
//78    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
//79    return $dom;
//80    }
```

Is there any way to get the script working for every IRI in Wikipedia or Wikisource? (I know that there is not always a `span#ws-title`, that's not my problem.)

Comment: Just FYI: those are not IRIs, they're just normal URLs with encoded characters.

Comment: OK, but aren't IRI's URL's which allow internationalized web addressing? Is this not the case if, you use ä ö ß which ar typically for Germany?

Comment: My understanding is that IRI has actual UTF-8 characters in them, i.e. `http://example.com/fööbär` rather than encoded characters (ASCII only), i.e. `http://example.com/f%F6%F6b%E4r`). (Not an expert, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable can chime in.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome question! :)

They seem to filter by user agent, try something like

```
<?php
ini_set("user_agent", "Descriptive user agent string");
file_get_contents("http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/".urlencode("Am_Bächle"));
?>
```

you can probably skip the urlencode part since I just used it to test whether the encode was right.

Please note that wikisource obviously dislikes automated parsing of their content on the web pages. Nonetheless there *might* be an API available for wikibots and the like, **ask them** or search the community pages. The API will be much easier to handle anyway.

Comment: I'll ask in the community about the parsing, but i don't get it why I could parse some pages and others not... i'll ask them :)

Comment: You shouldn't impersonate a browser by spoofing the User-Agent. You should use a descriptive User-Agent instead.

Comment: @svick: You should not do this at all. Wikisource has a reason why they disallow some user agents. I only used a different user agent to prove it is possible. This is why I wrote the last paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to characters or encoding. You're getting 403 because of [the Wikimedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy), which says:

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

That's what you should do: set the User-Agent header to something that identifies your application and can be used to contact you in case of problems.

That being said, accessing the pages directly is probably the worst way to get the date you want. You should instead use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), or, if you want to access lots of pages, [the database dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download).

Comment: Thank you! I just downloaded the the file i need :)